# Co- and contravariant types in generic priority queue

Tags: scala, covariance, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to implement in Scala a generic data type parameterized on a type `T`, which should be `Ordered[T]`. Specifically, it's a persistent version of Sleator & Tarjan's [skew heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_heap) priority queues. After adding lots of complicated type parameter declarations based on the explanation [here](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p57.scala) and in Odersky-Spoon-Venners, I'm down to one compiler error before I can test/debug the actual functionality.

Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
abstract class SkewHeap[+T] {
  // merge two heaps
  def +[U >: T <% Ordered[U]](x : SkewHeap[U]) : SkewHeap[U]
  // remove least element, return new heap
  def delMin[U >: T <% Ordered[U]] : SkewHeap[U]
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def min : T
  def left  : SkewHeap[T]
  def right : SkewHeap[T]
}

case object Leaf extends SkewHeap[Nothing] {
  def +[U <% Ordered[U]](that : SkewHeap[U]) = that
  def isEmpty = true
}

case class Node[+T](left : SkewHeap[T],
                    min : T,
                    right : SkewHeap[T]) extends SkewHeap[T] {
  def +[U >: T <% Ordered[U]](that : SkewHeap[U]) : SkewHeap[U] =
    that match {
      case Leaf        => this
      case Node(l,y,r) => if (this.min < that.min)
                            Node(this.right + that, this.min, this.left)
                          else
                            Node(this + that.right, that.min, that.left)
    }

  def delMin[U >: T <% Ordered[U]] : SkewHeap[U] = left + right
  def isEmpty = false
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
skew.scala:28: error: no implicit argument matching parameter type (T) => Ordered[T] was found.
   def delMin[U >: T <% Ordered[U]] : SkewHeap[U] = left + right
```

I've tried several variants of the declaration of `delMin`, but to no avail. I think I understand the problem (method `+` wants an ordering guarantee), but where should I put this? And is there a way to declare `delMin` as returning `SkewHeap[T]` instead of `SkewHeap[U]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
abstract class SkewHeap[+T <% Ordered[T]] {
  // merge two heaps
  def +[U >: T <% Ordered[U]](x : SkewHeap[U]) : SkewHeap[U]
  // remove least element, return new heap
  def delMin : SkewHeap[T]
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def min : T
  def left  : SkewHeap[T]
  def right : SkewHeap[T]
}

case object Leaf extends SkewHeap[Nothing] {
  def +[U <% Ordered[U]](that : SkewHeap[U]) = that
  def isEmpty = true
  def min = throw new RuntimeException
  def left = throw new RuntimeException
  def right = throw new RuntimeException
  def delMin = throw new RuntimeException
}
```

Scala isn't sure how to compare `this.min` with `that.min`, becuase it wants to convert `this.min` to an `Ordered[T]` and `that.min` to an `Ordered[U]`. The simplest answer is to add a type conversion to force `this.min` to an `Ordered[U]`.

```
case class Node[+T <% Ordered[T]](left : SkewHeap[T],
                    min : T,
                    right : SkewHeap[T]) extends SkewHeap[T] {
  def +[U >: T <% Ordered[U]](that : SkewHeap[U]) : SkewHeap[U] =
    that match {
      case Leaf        => this
      case Node(l,y,r) => if ((this.min:Ordered[U]) < that.min)
                            Node(this.right + that, this.min, this.left)
                          else
                            Node(this + that.right, that.min, that.left)
    }

  def delMin : SkewHeap[T] = left + right
  def isEmpty = false
}
```

But you have a big problem with all of these implicits, and that problem is that you could get a different `Ordered` implementation in every context where you use the view bound `<% Ordered[Something]`, so you should really look for some other way of making sure your ordering is consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the `<%` syntactic sugar, I suggest that you manually add the implicit parameter.  It's a lot more controlled, and certainly easier to see what's going on:

```
def delMin[U >: T](implicit ord: U => Ordered[U]): SkewHeap[U] = left + right
```

The problem with using the `<%` operator in your case is it binds to `T` rather than `U`.  Thus, it was looking for a function of type `T => Ordered[U]`.  In fact, all of your methods are doing this, and I suspect that's not the behavior you wanted.

Also, a minor note on idioms: it is customary to use the `++` operator for concatenating two collections, and the `+` operator for adding a single value to an existing collection (see `Vector`, `ArrayBuffer`, and pretty much any collection in the standard library).

Comment: Nope, it binds to `U`. `scala> def +[U >: T <% Ordered[U]] =0; $plus: [U >: T](implicit evidence$1: (U) => Ordered[U])Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the other suggestions, you may consider to switch from Ordered to an implicit parameter Ordering[T], which is much easier to control and gives you more flexibility.

[Edit]
A very simple example:

```
class Foo[T](val t:T)(implicit val ord: Ordering[T]) {
   def min(that:Foo[T]) = if (ord.compare(this.t, that.t) < 0) this else that
}
```

After this you can use Foo for all types that have an ordering. Of course you can make one yourself:

```
implicit object barOrdering extends Ordering[Bar] {...}
```

After this, you could create a `Foo[Bar]`.

(Sorry for the very basic example, my PC broke down and I have no IDE available...)

Comment: Ok, how do I do that? +1 if you can point me to a good explanation with examples. I've found neither _Programming in Scala_ nor _Programming Scala_ very clear on these issues (but haven't read either cover to cover yet).

Comment: I've still not been able to implement your suggestion. It complains about "no implicit argument matching parameter type `Ordering[Nothing]`" and other type errors.